# Apache Cassandra configuration With Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration, cassandra, datastax

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

```
2016-10-23 20:18:26.074 ERROR 4144 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testrepo': Error creating bean with name 'testRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is **org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;**; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepo': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CassandraSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'converter' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'converter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/tulabetv/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Using dependencies:

- Cassandra-driver-core-3.1.1.jar
- spring-data-cassandra-1.4.4.RELEASE
- cassandra-driver-dse-3.0.0-rc1.jar
- DB Apache Cassandra 3.9.0.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Data Cassandra project at 1.4.x does not support the Cassandra driver version 3.0 or up, it seems to be linked to 2.1.x so you will not be able to use a Cassandra version greater than 2.1 See [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.x/pom.xml#L38)

Looking at 1.5 milestone it does support Cassandra driver 3.0, and truck in the repo looks like it will be spring data cassandra 2.0 and support the 3.1 version of the driver.